# Spring controller method is getting called multiple times

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, controller, spring-restcontroller

I have a spring boot application which acts as a service to a ionic app, and whenever I call an api the controller methods gets called twice for eg:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("/sendSMS")
public class SendSMSController {

@Autowired
SendSMSService sendSMSService;
protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

@PostMapping(value = "/sendMessage", produces = "application/json",consumes = "application/json")
public  Map<String, Object> sendMessage(@RequestBody UserRegistration userRegistration) {   
    logger.info("Api sendMessage test");
     return sendSMSService.sendMessage(userRegistration);
}
}
```

When I call http://localhost:8080/CEPMobileService/sendSMS/sendMessage from postman, the api /sendMessage gets called twice as shown in the logs

```
15/10/2020 09:32:29 PM |  INFO | http-nio-8080-exec-4 | SendSMSController | Api sendMessage test
15/10/2020 09:32:29 PM |  INFO | http-nio-8080-exec-4 | SendSMSController | Api sendMessage test
15/10/2020 09:32:29 PM |  INFO | http-nio-8080-exec-4 | SendSMSServiceImpl | Phone number--> 
[0000000000, 0000000000]
15/10/2020 09:32:29 PM |  INFO | http-nio-8080-exec-4 | SendSMSServiceImpl | Phone number--> 
[0000000000, 0000000000]
15/10/2020 09:32:29 PM |  INFO | http-nio-8080-exec-4 | SendSMSServiceImpl | Message number-->In 
distress!!!
15/10/2020 09:32:29 PM |  INFO | http-nio-8080-exec-4 | SendSMSServiceImpl | Message number-->In 
distress!!!
15/10/2020 09:32:29 PM |  INFO | http-nio-8080-exec-4 | SendSMSServiceImpl | numbers---->0000000000, 
0000000000
15/10/2020 09:32:29 PM |  INFO | http-nio-8080-exec-4 | SendSMSServiceImpl | numbers---->0000000000, 
0000000000
```

Not just this api every api in the code gets called twice and this happens when deployed in Azure too. An answer suggested it maybe due to JSONView, but it is not available in my system  and other answers couldn't help, any solutions please?

Comment: If the same API called twice then why the phone number is different for both the requests.

Comment: Have you debugged your code? May the issue is with the logger.

Comment: do you have any kind of filters somewhere located acting ? or check for chain.doFilter(req, res)

Comment: @Alien I forgot to edit those phone numbers while asking the question. It's actually the same number

Comment: @silentsudo No sir, no such filters.

Comment: @ShivakumarN.R , No filters . Then it may be logger configuration problem, Did you set any specific logger config.

Comment: @ShivakumarN.R , Check this question , As spring provides more default configuration for logging , you may need to check your pom and add needed log config file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51872338/double-log-files-in-spring-boot-application

Comment: @anavaraslamurep yes it was a logger configuration error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by anavaraslamurep and Ismail, it was indeed a logger error, I have used log4j and the messages were logged twice as I had configured appenders. I solved it setting additivity to false, here is the configuration:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
<Properties>
    <!-- azure server log -->
    <Property name="log-path">d:\home\Citizen_Engagement_App_V3_logs
    </Property>
</Properties>

<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="file-log"
        fileName="${log-path}/citizen_app_application.log"
        filePattern="${log-path}/%d{dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a}/application-log-%i.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout
            pattern="%d{dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a} | %5level | %t | %c{1} | %m%n" />
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"
                modulate="true" />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>

    <RollingFile name="error-log" fileName="${log-path}/application_error.log"
        filePattern="${log-path}/errorlog/%d{yyyy}/%d{MMM}/%d{dd}/application-log-%i- 
  error.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout
            pattern="%d{dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a} | %5level | %t | %c{1} | %m%n" />
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"
                modulate="true" />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>

    <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout
            pattern="%d{dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a} | %5level | %t | %c{1} | %m%n" />
    </Console>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>

    <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="file-log" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.trinity" level="ALL" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="file-log" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.trinity" level="ALL" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="file-log" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="kafka" level="ALL" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="file-log" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="jms" level="ALL" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="file-log" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </logger>

    <Root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="error-log" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```